# At first show RecyclerView ItemDecoration is drawn behind item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to add itemDecoration only to one item. It works, but at first show decoration is drawn without its own space. But when I start scrolling it will get its own space. Below is the code that I took partially from [here](https://blog.entelect.co.za/view/9627/how-to-android-recyclerview-item-decorations)

```
View spacer;

    public NewMessageHeaderDecoration() {
        spacer = null; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDraw(c, parent, state);

        if (spacer == null) { // If layout is not already inflated
            spacer = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_holder_new_messages_header, parent, false);
            fixLayoutSize(spacer, parent);
        }

        // go through all the recycler views parents
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            int pos = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
            long msgSerial = ((ChatAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItemSerial(pos);

            if(msgSerial == 40) {

                c.save(); 
                c.translate(0, child.getTop() - 2 - spacer.getHeight());
                spacer.draw(c);
                c.restore(); 
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || position == 0 || spacer == null) {
            return;
        }

        outRect.top = 2 + spacer.getHeight(); 
    }

    protected void fixLayoutSize(View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view.getLayoutParams() == null) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        int childWidth = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                parent.getPaddingLeft() + parent.getPaddingRight(), view.getLayoutParams().width);
        int childHeight = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                parent.getPaddingTop() + parent.getPaddingBottom(), view.getLayoutParams().height);

        view.measure(childWidth, childHeight);

        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

Comment: why `c.save();` in `else` ?

Comment: removed it, it was artefact from my tests

Comment: the extra space is because in `getItemOffsets` you are extending offsets for every view which position != 0, you should do that only for view which msgSerial == 40

Comment: you are right. I added my check to set extra space only to one place. Now My problem is on first show decoration is added above item(decoration layer is drawn on parent item, without its own space). But after scrolling list it placed into correct place with needed space.

Comment: @pskink I updated my question, can you check it?

Comment: I just debugged it. For first time getItemOffsets() is not called. But when I scroll it away from screen, its called.

Comment: what do you mean not called, jusr add some `Log.d` with `position` varaible and see the logcat

Comment: When I open list first time, header is already on the screen and by logcat getItemOffsets is not called yet. But when I scroll down list(so header goes away), and then scroll up(so header is visible again) getItemOffsets is called.

Comment: getItemOffsets is called, you are right. I placed logcat under If check inside getItemOffsets, thats why I saw it only after particular situation. Sorry to waste your time.